# Epoch time difference in Pig

Tags: time, apache-pig, difference, epoch

I have 3 columns which contains `start_time` , `end_time` and `tags`. Times are represented in epoch time format as shown in example below. I want to find the the rows which have 1 hour time difference between them.

Example:

```
Start_time     End_Time    Tags
1235000081    1235000501  "Answered"
1235000081    1235000551  "Answered"
```

I need to fetch the tags column if the time diff is less than an hour.

I want do it in `PIG` - can anyone kindly help?

Comment: we can kindly help you if you can kindly provide your efforts to achieve a proper result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

input.txt

```
1235000081  1235000501  Answered
1235000081  1235000551  Answered
```

pig script

```
A =  Load '/home/kishore/input.txt' as (col1:long, col2:long, col3:chararray);
B = Foreach A generate ToDate(col1) as startdate,ToDate(col2) as enddate,col3;    
C = Filter B by GetHour(enddate)-GetHour(startdate) == 1;   
Dump C;
```

you can filter the row based on your condition like >,< ,==

Comment: Thanks, However I need to call /define any UDF for GetHour ?

Comment: I tried to DUMP the output from relation B, i get wrong values..                          like                                                                                                       describe B;                                                                                                    B: {StartTime: datetime,EndTime: datetime}                                      DUMP B;                                                                                          (1970-01-15T00:03:20.081-07:00,1970-01-15T00:03:20.501-07:00)

Answer (score 0):

In case if you want to keep date fields as timestamps the solution is following:

```
data =  LOAD '/path/to/your/input' as (Start_Time:long, End_Time:long, Tags:chararray);
data_proc = FOREACH data GENERATE *, ToDate(Start_Time*1000) as Start_Time,ToDate(End_Time*1000) as End_Time;    
output = FILTER data_proc BY GetHour(End_Time)-GetHour(Start_Time) == 1;   
Dump @;
```

The one crucial thing is that Pig ToDate UDF needs a timestamp up to milliseconds precision thus you will have simply multiply your date fields by 1000 before using this UDF.